# Why is not getting stored in the array?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var reporter = []

fetch("http://localhost:3000")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    response.forEach(element => {
      reporter.push(element)
    });
  })

console.log(reporter)
```

I have a fetch function which gets an array from port 3000, but I am unable to store it in the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is, just not *yet*. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: instead of foreach just set reporter=response; and as for the console your data is asyc

Comment: The console.log executed before the response generated. You have to console it inside the last .then()

Comment: I guess you are joking

Comment: move console.log into .then block

Answer (score 0):

Console log is called before the fetch is finished. Wait for the response or use console log in a following then clause

```js
var reporter = []

fetch("http://localhost:3000")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    response.forEach(element => {
      reporter.push(element)
    });
  })
  .then(console.log(reporter)
```